# ado.net "No mapping exists from object type xo.Player to a known managed provider native type."

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I'm trying to connect a DB to an XO game I made in C#.net
now I already got a table and I'm trying to insert values into it and i get an error

This is my code:

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection
        (@"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=ExampleDB;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.CommandText = "insert into XOhalloffame (PlayerName ,Winnings, Losses) values ('@name', '@win', '@lose')";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", Session["player1"]as Player);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("win",0);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("win",0);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
```

** the `session` of player1 is an asp textbox, i want the player to insert the name dynamicly.

the Error is:

`No mapping exists from object type xo.Player to a known managed provider native type.`

Comment: You're adding two `win` parameters.

Comment: Also, if you win twice with the same name, you'll have two rows instead of one row displaying two wins. (Or, if your DB table is set up so the `name` must be unique, the code will throw.)

Comment: And I can't be certain, but if you've got two textboxes (one each for player1 and player2), then you're inserting player 1's name every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `INSERT` string, replace the following

```
values ('@name', '@win', '@lose')
```

With

```
values (@name, @win, @lose)
```

You do not need apostrophes when declaring scalar variables in a SQL query.

Also you need to put the `@` symbol in your `cmd.Paramaters.AddWithValue()` calls like so:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", yourValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Win", yourvalue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lose", yourValue);
```

To address the error however, I think you are trying to pass a `Player` object into your query, when you really just want the Player's name.  Without seeing your `Player` implementation it is hard to say but you want something like this.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Session["player1"].Text);
```

The error is telling you that a `Player` is not a known type to SQL and thus cannot be inserted into a column with (likely) varchar typing.  You just need to input the actual Text from the text box, or the `Name` property of your `Player` object.

I realize this answer covers more than your question, but you will likely run into more errors if you don't fix the syntax.

Comment: You've got a lowercase 'v' in your second `AddWithValue`.

Comment: yes i did a set get on the players name, on forgot to add it. its working now !!! thanks you !!

Comment: *"Also you need to put the @ symbol in your cmd.Paramaters.AddWithValue() calls like so:"* no you don't, if you leave it off `SqlParameter` will automatically add it for you.